# Sharing mdf file on a network

Tags: sql-server

I want to use my SQL Server Database application on sharing basis. I just added an mdf from Add New Item, made table and then connected with my application using datasets. 
I donot have network to test. I want to know if this application will work fine on a network (I will just share the folder containing my application files and mdf file and make a shortcut to application exe on network computer. I use this method for Access database and it works fine. Will it work for mdf also?

Also, do I need to install SQL server on client computers too or it is enough to install on main computer containing database?

Thanks

Comment: What for application? Asp.Net? WinForm/WPF?  Java? / Access?

Comment: Install a server machine in your network, install SQL Server on it, and attach your MDF file to that central SQL Server - that's the best way to do it. Your client computers only need the .NET framework or another way of connecting to the central SQL Server - you don't need the full server installation on every client machine...

Comment: do u mean install server on main computer, that other computers connect to?  It is a winform application

Answer (score 0):

MDF files should not resides on network and by default it is restricted to sql server to open databases from network share.

Even if you'll make it to open DB from network with help of TRACE flags - the resulting DB will not be neither reliable, nor fast. And only one instance of sql server can use the MDF file in one moment.

Of course you can redistribute MDF over network, but working with DB in it over network - it is not only **worst** scenario ever but also the **nightmare** scenario.

Comment: mdf resides on server, other computer just access it through the short cut to exe.  Not right way?

Comment: The only way to access database inside MDF - is thru Sql Server Engine. So - yes, it is absolutely not right way.

Comment: So just to summarise, I provide the database with application and user will attach them to SQL server instance.  In my application, I set connection string to connect to that instance.  But hoe to get server name?  Can I use .\sqlexpress?  Is sqlexpress always there when sqlserver is installed?

Comment: Could u also suggest the connection string?

Comment: Server=YourServerName;Database=YourDBName;User ID=Username;PWD=Password

Comment: Another favour, please give me code to get server name so I could ask user to put it when prompted by my client program.  Will it be ok if I always attach it with Default instance (SqlExpress)

Comment: Server name consists of two parts: MACHINENAME\INSTANCENAME where MACHINENAME - is network name or IP address of host where sql server resides, and instancename - instance of sql server, in your case likely it will be something like this: SERVERNAME\SqlExpress

Answer (score 0):

MDF are not made for using them over network. they are NOT comparable to access files. The files need single process access. Over network you will get the same trouble as you can have with access files. Locking problems and maybe corrupt files.

If you want to use MSSQL databases over network you really consider to use a **SQL-Server**.